# Drupal content title doesn't show

Tags: drupal-6

When i create a content, content title doesn't show, in preview mode it looks ok, but when i posted the content the title doesn't show?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Are you using a custom theme? Do you have any modules installed that might be relevant? Are there custom modules involved? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the $title variable is being printed somewhere in the page.tpl.php file of your theme.

```
echo $title;
```